# Wrong data on Magento 1.9.3.4 dashboard graph

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have a Magento site which is showing incorrect/incomplete data on the dashboard graph(version1.9.3.4).

In the order history I can see there were 11 completed orders in October, and 21 in September. The dashboard however, only shows 8 and 9 orders.

Likewise with all other months and store views, the data does not match up. I have tried refreshing statistics without any change to the dashboard. Is there any way this can be fixed or any indication of what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: try start  reindex process

Comment: Hi bxN5, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately a reindex didn't resolve. It was my first port of call.